# How to get the total count after Kaminari pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, kaminari

I am using rails 3.2. I am paginating my results using .page(1).per_page(10)

like

```
@users = User.method().page(1).per_page(10)
```

Now how to find the total count of the users from the pagination

As because `@users.count` gives **10** from the first page and not the total count

How to get the **total count of the users even after pagination**

EDIT : `@users.total_count` gives the whole paginated count

Answer (score 101):

As mentioned in the question, you can get the total count of the records with

```
@users.total_count
```

I've added this as an answer for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@users.total_count`.

However, if you're trying to get the total count for each page, i.e. something like:

`20 of 135 results`

then `total_count` will just return 135, not the number of results on the page.

If you want to handle this case as well as the case where the number of results is less than the pagination result number, then I'd go with something like this:

```rb
(per_size > @users.total_count) ? @users.total_count : per_size
```

where `per_size` is the value you are setting for your `per` scope ([docs here](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari#the-per-scope)).

Answer (score 0):

User.count would give you the count but it would hit the db. If you are using mongodb @user.length would give you the total count

Comment: The answer is total_count, @user.length will give you the same 10 because of the pagination.